# Any idea why I can't paint the texture on a proper uv unwrapped object?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

Video reference: https://cloudmails-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/tp053611_mail_apu_edu_my/EZ5KVuWNAABLmH57L7UmCqQBt_Nl0YNnV8wvT3YIVjsVtQ?nav=eyJyZWZlcnJhbEluZm8iOnsicmVmZXJyYWxBcHAiOiJPbmVEcml2ZUZvckJ1c2luZXNzIiwicmVmZXJyYWxBcHBQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldlYiIsInJlZmVycmFsTW9kZSI6InZpZXciLCJyZWZlcnJhbFZpZXciOiJNeUZpbGVzTGlua0NvcHkifX0&e=Iehqpf

I seemed to be able to paint on some region but unable to paint on the region I needed, any possible cause of this?
[image]

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: Looking at your video, it does not look properly unwrapped.  There are faces with 0 UV area.  If a face doesn't have any area, you can't paint on it.

Comment: or you have given another material to this face, hard to tell without the file